# Problema com cadastro de doação

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um projeto final do curso de t.i, so que estou com um problema no cadastro das doações, quando logo com admin o cadastro e feito com sucesso, mas quando eu logo com doador nao cadastrar, obs: quando tento colocar o valor por sessao para puxar o doador logado e jogar no input para aparecer o nome dele e puxar, para saber quem doou a doação. Quando nao tem um valor atribuido, ou seja , deixo uma lista de varios doadores no select cadastrar normalmente, so que preciso restringir.

**Formulário de Doação**

```
<?php
require_once '../Controle/DAO/classeDoadorDAO.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['DoadorLogado']) && $_SESSION['DoadorLogado'] == 1) {
    $DoadorLogado = true;
    $IdDoadorLogado = $_SESSION['IdDoadorLogado'];
    $NomeDoadorLogado = $_SESSION['NomeDoadorLogado'];
}

if (isset($_SESSION['iddoador']) && $_SESSION['iddoador'] != NULL) {
   $idDoador=$_SESSION['iddoador'];
} else {
   $idDoador=0;
}

// $idBeneficiario = $_SESSION['idbeneficiario'];

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Formulário</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="area">
<form id="formDoacao"
name="formDoacao"
method="POST"
action="../Controle/controladorDoacao.php?ACAO=cadastrar"
enctype="multipart/form-data">

<legend>Doação</legend>
<input class="idDoacao" name="idDoacao"
type="hidden"
value=""><br /><br />

<label for="nome">Nome:</label>
<input class="nome" name="nome"
type="text"
value=""><br /><br />
<label for="descricao">Descrição:</label>
<input class="descricao" name="descricao"
type="text"
value=""><br /><br />


<input type="file" id="img" name="img" value="" />
<br /><br />


<input class="dataentrada" name="dataentrada"
type="hidden"
value=""><br /><br />


<input class="datasaida" name="datasaida"
type="hidden"
value=""><br /><br />

<?php
if (isset($DoadorLogado) && $DoadorLogado=TRUE) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='doador' value='" . $NomeDoadorLogado . "' >";
} else {
    $doadorDAO = new classeDoadorDAO();
    $doadores = $doadorDAO->selecionarDoador($idDoador);
}
?>

<br><br>


<button class="btn btn-cadastrar" name="submit" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>

<a href="../index.php" class="btn btn-voltar">Voltar para página inicial</a><br>
<br>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Método da classe DAO Doador**

```
public function selecionarDoador($idDoador) {

    try {
        $pdo = conexao::getInstance();
        $sql = "SELECT iddoador, nome FROM doador;";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<select name='doador'>";
        echo"<option value=''>Selecione Doador</option>";

        while ($doador = $stmt->fetchObject(__CLASS__)) {
            if ($doador->iddoador == $idDoador){
                echo"<option value='" . $doador->iddoador . "' selected>" .
                $doador->nome . "</option>";
            } else {
              echo"<option value='" . $doador->iddoador . "'>" . 
              $doador->nome . "</option>";
            }
        }
        echo ' </select>';
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
       echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Por gentileza, alguém saberia me informar o que está errado. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Controlador Doação**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['ACAO'])) {
    $acao = $_GET['ACAO'];

    switch ($acao) {
        case 'listar':
            require_once '../Modelo/classeDoacao.php';
            require_once '../Controle/DAO/classeDoacaoDAO.php';
            require_once '../Modelo/classeFoto.php';

            $doacaoDAO = new classeDoacaoDAO;
            $doacoes = array();
            $doacoes = $doacaoDAO->listarDoacao();

            echo "<div class='linha'>";
            echo "<div class='coluna_nome'>Nome</div>";
            echo "<div class='coluna_descricao'>Descricao</div>";
            echo "<div class='coluna_dataentrada'>DataEntrada</div>";
            echo "<div class='coluna_datasaida>DataSaida</div>";

            echo "</div>";
            if (isset($doacoes)) {
                foreach ($doacoes as $doacao) {
                    echo "<div class='linha'>";
                    echo "<div class='coluna_nome'>" . $doacao->nome . "</div>";
                    echo "<div class='coluna_descricao'>" . $doacao->descricao . "</div>";
                    echo "<img src=' " . $doacao->url . "'height='250' width='250' alt='Foto' /><br />";
                    echo "<div class='coluna_dataentrada'> " . $doacao->dataentrada . "</div>";
                    echo "<div class='coluna_datasaida>" . $doacao->datasaida . "</div>";

//                    echo "<div class='coluna_excluir'>"
//                    . "<a href='index.php?PAGINA=excluirDoacao&&idDoacao="
//                    . $doacao->idDoacao . "' onclick='return checkDelete()'>"
//                    . "X</a></div>";
//                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
//            session_start();
//            $_SESSION['doacao'] = serialize($doacaoes);
//            header('Location:Visao/listarDoacao.php');

            break;
        case 'cadastrar':
            require_once '../Modelo/classeDoacao.php';
            require_once '../Controle/DAO/classeDoacaoDAO.php';
            require_once '../Modelo/classeFoto.php';

            $nome = $_POST["nome"];
            $descricao = $_POST["descricao"];
            $dataentrada = $_POST["dataentrada"];
            $datasaida = $_POST["datasaida"];
            $foto = $_FILES["img"];
            $iddoador = $_POST['doador'];

            // Se a foto estiver sido selecionada
            if (!empty($foto["name"])) {
                $error = array();

                // Largura máxima em pixels
                $largura = 2000;
                // Altura máxima em pixels
                $altura = 2000;
                // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes
                $tamanho = 6000000;

                // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
                if (!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])) {
                    $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
                }

                // Pega as dimensões da imagem
                $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);

                // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida
                if ($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
                    $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar " . $largura . " pixels";
                }

                // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida
                if ($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
                    $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar " . $altura . " pixels";
                }

                // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido
                if ($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
                    $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo " . $tamanho . " bytes";
                }

                // Se não houver nenhum erro
                if (count($error) == 0) {

                    $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['img']['name'], -4));

                    // Gera um nome único para a imagem
                    $nome_imagem = "foto" . date("dmY_hms") . $ext;

                    // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
                    $url = "../imagem/foto/" . $nome_imagem;

                    // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
                    if (move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $url)) {
                        echo 'Cadastrado';
                    } else {

                        echo 'Erro cadastro';
                    }
                    $urlBanco = "/imagem/foto/" . $nome_imagem;

                    // Insere os dados no banco
                    // Se houver mensagens de erro, exibe-as
                }
            }

            $novoDoacao = new classeDoacao();
            $novoDoacao->setNome($nome);
            $novoDoacao->setDescricao($descricao);
            $novoDoacao->setIddoador($iddoador);
//            $novoDoacao->setimagem($imagem);
            $novoDoacao->setdataEntrada($dataentrada);
            $novoDoacao->setdataSaida($datasaida);

            $novaFoto = new classeFoto();
            $novaFoto->setUrl($url);

            $doacaoDAO = new classeDoacaoDAO();
            $cadastrarDoacao = $doacaoDAO->cadastrarDoacao($novoDoacao, $novaFoto);

            if ($cadastrarDoacao == FALSE) {
                header('Location:../index.php?PAGINA=principal&MSG=Cadastro Não Realizado');
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Cadastrado com Sucesso');
                     window.location.href='../index.php?PAGINA=listarDoacao';
                      </script>";
            }
            break;

        case 'resgatar':
            require_once '../Modelo/classeDoacao.php';
            require_once '../Controle/DAO/classeDoacaoDAO.php';


            $doacaoDAO = new classeDoacaoDAO;
            $doacaoAlterada = new classeDoacao();


            $iddoacao = $_POST["idDoacao"];
            $idbeneficiario = $_POST["beneficiario"];
            $doacaoAlterada->setIdbeneficiario($idbeneficiario);
            $doacaoAlterada->setIddoacao($iddoacao);

            $doacaoDAO->resgatarDoacao($doacaoAlterada);



    if ($doacaoAlterada == FALSE) {
                header('Location:../index.php?PAGINA=principal&MSG=regaste Não Realizado');
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Resgate com Sucesso');
                     window.location.href='../index.php?PAGINA=listarDoacao';
                      </script>";
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi sua dúvida completamente, vamos às dúvidas:

Quando estiver logado como **Doador**, o sistema deve listar apenas ele mesmo na lista de doadores.

Quando estiver logado com **qualquer outro que não for doador**, por exemplo *Administrador*, então ele deve listar todos os doadores, procede?

Agora quanto ao fato de não estar salvando, tenho uma hipótese:

Quando você está logado como **Doador**, o **valor do campo** é o nome do doador em si, como mostra a linha de código a seguir:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='doador' value='" . $NomeDoadorLogado . "' >";
```

Já quando logado como *Administrador*, por exemplo o valor do campo é o **id do doador**, como mostra a linha de código a seguir:

```
echo"<option value='" . $doador->iddoador . "'>" . $doador->nome . "</option>";
```

Sendo assim, quando estiver logado como **Doador**, você estará mandando ele salvar um valor do tipo "*String*", e quando logado com outro usuário estará mandando ele salvar um valor "*Numérico*".

Se puder mostrar a sua classe *Controle/controladorDoacao.php*, talvez ajude a compreender o problema e ver se a minha hipótese está correta.

Abraço

Comment: tipo to querendo restringi a lista como doador para mostrar de acordo com o usuario nesse caso é o doador, que nem na foto cadastrar a doacao com o nome do doador logado, e no admin mostrar todos os doadores logados.

Comment: o controlador doacao ta em baixo.

Comment: To querendo pegar o iddoador pra jogar na doacao e saber quem doou aquela doacao, e coloquei o input pra restringir atraves do doador logado, so que nao ta cadastrando. Pq o valor foi preenchido , quando uso o select e tem as opções de escolher cadastrar, mas quando limito nao.

Comment: Anderson, como dito, ele não cadastra justamente por conta disso: **$iddoador = $_POST['doador'];**.
Você espera o _id do doador_ para salvar no banco, mas quando está logado com o doador, você está mandando ele salvar o _nome dele_.

Comment: Para ver melhor o problema, você pode printar essa variável no controller **$iddoador = $_POST['doador'];**, e você verá que quando está logado como administrador você salva o valor do *ID* e quando logado como o doador você salva o *nome do usuário logado*. Entendeu o problema?

Comment: vlw mano resolveu aqui muito obrigado.

Comment: Anderson, se a minha resposta foi útil, por favor não esqueça de votar positivamente nela :)